# this browser dosen't support the ApI's requiered to use the firebase SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
import '../css/index.scss';
import './all.min.js';
import Highway from '@dogstudio/highway';
import Fade from './transition';
import CustomRendererTienda from './renderTienda.js';
import CustomRendererCompras from './renderCompras.js';
import CustomRendererIndex from './renderIndex.js';
import {configuracionFirebase} from './firebase.js';

firebase.initializeApp(configuracionFirebase());

    const H = new Highway.Core({
        transitions: {
            default: Fade   
        },
        renderers: {
            home:CustomRendererIndex,
            tienda: CustomRendererTienda,
            compras:CustomRendererCompras
          }
    });
```

the error "this browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).- URL https://almacen-18f28.firebaseapp.com/js.7bd27977.js-Line:1 -Column:1006-error object:{"code":"messaging/unsupported-browser","name":"FirebaseError"}" appears when i run the web page in facebook browser, in the most web browser the page run good.
I coment this line

```
 firebase.initializeApp(configuracionFirebase());
```

y the css and js load good, how to solved this problem? 
Is posible that firebase work very good in the Facebook browser? or i will have to charge mi web page in the external navigator of movil device?

Comment: It means the native JS APIs required to run Firebase aren't available in the Facebook browser, which is to be expected since it's a very minimal implementation of an HTTP client. You will have to use polyfills. And looking at the [required browser APIs](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/0beb028de38c74198592f47618400f9905d605da/packages/messaging/index.ts#L86) it doesn't look like there is a polyfill for all of the APIs potentially missing (`serviceWorker`, `PushManager`, `Notification`, etc...)

Comment: sure that it's not a typo? `configurationFirebase` instead of `configuracionFirebase`?

Comment: no es error tipográfico mi lengua nativa es español, gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing is from Firebase Cloud Messaging -- it will throw that error when it is initialized in any browser that doesn't support the standards necessary to receive web push notifications. You should call `firebase.messaging.isSupported()` before using the SDK and, if it returns false, just skip it.

Comment: thanks Michael Bleigh, si eso resulto ser el problema, deje de usar las notificaciones en mi web, por lo demas todo funciona ... muchas gracias.. saludos desde ecuador